# Improve performance of same partition by clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, partitioning, window-functions, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with 20+ columns, 45 millions rows. I am looking to summarize information for each Id with partition by, so that the numner of rows stay the same and information remains for each row

```
select min(Distance) over(partition by Id) as min_distance
, max(Distance) over(partition by Id) as max_distance
, avg(Distance) over(partition by Id) as mean_distance
, stdev(Distance) over(partition by Id) as sd_distance
, sum(Distance) over(partition by Id) as sum_distance
, min(Speed) over(partition by Id) as min_speed
, max(Speed) over(partition by Id) as max_speed
, avg(Speed) over(partition by Id) as mean_speed
, stdev(Speed) over(partition by Id) as sd_speed
```

A test of only 10000 rows has been running for 2 hours. I wonder if there is something we can do to improve the performance.

Comment: Get more hardware? 2 hours is astonishingly long - I would love to see what you use as SQL Server hardware AND to see the execution plan (which you tag but then do not give - shame).

Comment: Anyway, closing - this is a very specific question an falls into dba.stackexchange.com where the db specialists are.

Comment: Without table definition (including indexes) this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
select Id, MIN(Distance)  as min_distance
, max(Distance)  as max_distance
, avg(Distance)  as mean_distance
, stdev(Distance)  as sd_distance
, sum(Distance)  as sum_distance
, min(Speed)  as min_speed
, max(Speed)  as max_speed
, avg(Speed)  as mean_speed
, stdev(Speed)  as sd_speed
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```